# Run shell script after keycloak http endpoint is ready

Tags: docker, dockerfile, keycloak

Simplified scenario:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak
COPY ./initialize.sh /
RUN chmod +x initialize.sh
```

initialize.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl http://localhost:8080/auth
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

- start keycloak container
- execute the `initialize.sh` script after an `/auth` 
  http endpoint inside the container is ready
- use keycloak-cli to add test users and roles

The motivation behind is to create a keycloak container to be used together with https://www.testcontainers.org/ for integration testing.

The official `jboss/keycloak` image has a `KEYCLOAK_IMPORT` environment variable which enables realm import, but it is not possible to import users and roles which are needed for the integration tests.

Comment: You can show your docker log ? docker logs  id_container

Comment: Could you solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of docker [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck).

Healthcheck will determine when a container is healthy prior to starting its execution.

Add these lines in you `dockerfile`

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
  CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8080/auth || exit 1
```

OR

Modify your `docker run` command.

> docker run -itd --health-cmd "curl --fail http://localhost:8080/auth
>   || exit 1" --health-interval=5s --timeout=3s image-name

Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: @senjin-hajrulahovic let me know if it helps? If not I have something more to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

To export the entire realm (clients, user, roles ...) to a json file you can do:

```
docker exec -it keycloak_keycloak_1 opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh \
-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export \
-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile \
-Dkeycloak.migration.realmName=demo-realm \
-Dkeycloak.migration.usersExportStrategy=REALM_FILE \
-Dkeycloak.migration.file=/tmp/demo-realm.json
```

Then reference these file in `KEYCLOAK_IMPORT` variable as described in the docker documentation.